# How to compare two or more fields in a single array and calculate minimum value

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4, mule-esb

I need to compare the field(Doc) in a single array and if their values matched I need to calculate the minimum value of another filed(Number)

Here is an example of the array:

```
 [
    {

        "Doc": "test1",
        "Number": 91
    },

    {
        "Doc": "test1",
        "Number": 94
    },
        {
        "Doc": "test1",
        "Number": 40
    },
        {
        "Doc": "test2",
        "Number": 82
    },
        {
        "Doc": "test2",
        "Number": 80
    }
]
```

In the above array, if Doc is same I want to get the minimum value of the Number field. My output should be like this:

```
[
    {
        
        "Doc": "test1",
        "Number": 40
    }
        {
        "Doc": "test2",
        "Number": 80
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative using `valuesOf`:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
fun byDoc() = valuesOf(payload groupBy ((item, index) -> item.Doc)) 
fun minNumber(array : Array) = array minBy ((item) -> item.Number)
---
byDoc() map ((item, index) -> minNumber(item))
```

Comment: Appreciate your help @afelisatti. However, when I tried using your code sample in the dataweave playground, I am getting this error below. I am new to Mule and appreciate your response. Thanks again!     
Unexpected character '{' at payload@[14:9] (line:column), expected ']', while reading `payload` as Json.
 
14|         {
            ^
Trace:
  at main::main (line: 6, column: 1)

Comment: This solution is also working for me. I tested it on the dataweave playground. I didn't know valueOf could also be used here.

Answer (score 1):

First group by Doc, mapObject() to get the minimum of each group, then pluck() to get the expected output.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload groupBy ((item, index) -> item.Doc)
    mapObject ((value, key, index) -> (key): min(value.Number) )
    pluck ((value, key, index) -> { Doc: key, Number: value})
```

Input:

```json
[ 
    {

        "Doc": "STR23756",
        "Number": 91
    },

    {
        "Doc": "STR23756",
        "Number": 94
    },
        {
        "Doc": "STR23756",
        "Number": 40
    },
        {
        "Doc": "STR23757",
        "Number": 82
    },
        {
        "Doc": "STR23757",
        "Number": 80
    }
]
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "Doc": "STR23756",
    "Number": 40
  },
  {
    "Doc": "STR23757",
    "Number": 80
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you please show me an example of this. I've tried the solution but it's giving me the following dataweave error:
Invalid input 'g', expected Namespace (line 5, column 9):


5| payload groupBy ((item, index) -> item.Doc)
           ^
Location:
main (line: 5, column:9)

Comment: I tested and got the expected output. Not sure what is the problem that you are having.  I'll add the output in my answer.

Comment: Are you trying with the new official version of the playground? https://developer.mulesoft.com/learn/dataweave/

Comment: Its working for me now. Thank you so much for your answer! I do have another scenario where I have two similar arrays and I need to do the same codding i.e look for matching Doc field and get the least value of number. How would we do this similar scenario with two identical arrays?

Comment: You can try to adapt the script to the new structure or ask a new question.

Comment: Sure will do! Thanks @aled

Comment: what if I want to add additional fields in the output from my payload. I do have other fields that are in the same object that I need to capture. Please let me know if you would like me to post another question so I can post the sample payload and output. Thanks

Comment: That would different enough to warrant a different question with its own examples.

Answer (score 0):

### %dw 2.0
output application/json

payload groupBy $.Doc
mapObject ((item, key, index) -> (key): min(item.Number) )
pluck ((item, key, index) -> { Doc: key, Number: item})

Comment: this solution works as long as there is data in these fields. It fails if any of these fields are Null. Is there a way we look for Null value and don't include in this transformation?

Answer (score 0):

Both of these answers worked for me.

Solution# 1:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload groupBy ((item, index) -> item.Doc)
    mapObject ((value, key, index) -> (key): min(value.Number) )
    pluck ((value, key, index) -> { Doc: key, Number: value})
```

Solution# 2:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
fun byDoc() = valuesOf(payload groupBy ((item, index) -> item.Doc)) 
fun minNumber(array : Array) = array minBy ((item) -> item.Number)
---
byDoc() map ((item, index) -> minNumber(item))
```